# Replacing a word with nothing when that word is or isn't by itself with str_replace

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm trying to replace a certain word in my string with nothing, but I came across a problem. If that certain word is next to itself, it doesn't replace. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
$text1 = "text replace text replace text";
$text1 = str_replace(" replace "," ",$text1);

$text2 = "text replace replace text";
$text2 = str_replace(" replace "," ",$text2);

echo $text1;
echo $text2;
```

**Actual Results**

```
text text text
text replace text
```

**Expected Results**

```
text text text
text text
```

P.S: I also don't want to do something like str_replace("replace"," ",$text2), with the spaces to the left and right of "replace" taken off, because what if that word is part of another word? Then it'll replace it anyway, and it'll be wrong.

Comment: replace words first. then replace multiple spaces or you can use only reg expressions. str_replace goes only forward and not backtracking

Comment: regexps can look forward and backward so you can determine wether its a part of the word or its separate word.btw im sorry for my english

Comment: Remove one space from the end of your "replace" string is all you need. The solution is you've marked as correct is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** following comments i adapted my str_replace example and added regex example

With **str_replace** *(not recomended)*

```
str_replace(array(" replace "," replace ","  "),array(" "," "," "))
```

Checkout http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php if syntax error, but i think i recalled it right.

However, that is awkward to code, and not replicable in all cases.

With **regex**

Prob the way to go: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Im pretty rusty, but this should work:

```
$ret = 'test replace test replace replace dontreplace test';
$pattern = '/\breplace\b/i';
$ret = preg_replace($pattern,"",$ret);
var_dump($ret);
```

Comment: I don't think would be a 100%-solution for OP? As OP stated she didn't want to strip of the space(s) because what if the replace-string is a part of another word...

Comment: Thanks. This should be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp should work, maybe with a couple adjustments:

```
$word = 'someWordToReplace';  
$resultString = preg_replace('/(?:(?<= )|(?<=\A))'.$word.'(?:(?= )|(?=\Z))/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Does this work for `text replace text replace.`... ? Or how about `text replace replace replace.`. Normally I wouldn't bother commenting, but since we're doing the `what if` scenario I figured why not. Something tells me it's not working as one might hope for having all that lookaround, lookbehind stuff you've got in there.

Comment: @l'L'l now it works even with `replace replacetextreplace replace text replace replace` but(!!)this is why i wrote about adjustments. Now it works if word is surronded by simple space or BOL/EOL. You can add custom word-separators into my solution

Comment: Try putting a period on the end of the last replace. Hmmm... see what I mean? I could sit here all day and pick it apart, but I've really got better things to do. Generally I when I spend time answering a question I hope that someone might learn something from it (useful). No answer is ever going to be perfect and it's a waste of time picking apart someones stuff, especially for a stupid question such as the one asked here.

Comment: try adding it as a custom separator

Comment: @l'L'l its all stupid android app with tons of arrows xD 1 arrow for answer and second one for voting...stackoverflow app has very bad gui

Comment: I'm sorry that I was the one to break the exciting news to you... but I think we forgot about `"(replace)replacetextreplace-replace."` — :)

Comment: @l'L'l it shouldnt bereplaced and it wont be replaced ;-D

Comment: I don't use android, which arrows do you mean? the up-vote thing? i think maybeitmightbereplacedinanotheruniverse.

Comment: @l'L'l yeah. 2 arrows next each other. im using samsung galaxy 3 and sometimes i misclick...and in some cases there is only one arrow visible and im just clicking an arrow but then i realize that this is a vote button, not reply button :-D